# flutter app does not load local device language

Tags: flutter, dart, localization

I implemented the Easy localization package on my app, and it works fine when i use **the app radio button** switch between the different languages. But the aim it is not to let users change language, it is to load local device language and set the app with the local language.
I have changed device language in device settings, but when i re-open the app, language does not change.

**Here the main.dart:**

```
  void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await EasyLocalization.ensureInitialized();

  runApp(
    EasyLocalization(
      supportedLocales: [
        Locale('en', 'US'),
        Locale('it', 'IT'),
        Locale('fr', 'FR')
      ],
      path: 'assets/translations',
      // <-- change the path of the translation files
      fallbackLocale: Locale('en', 'US'),
      //assetLoader: CodegenLoader(),
      child: MyLangApp(),
    ),
  );
}
```

Here the MyLangApp:

```
  class MyLangApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyLangApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyLangApp> createState() => _MyLangAppState();
}

class _MyLangAppState extends State<MyLangApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      localizationsDelegates: context.localizationDelegates,
      supportedLocales: context.supportedLocales,
      locale: context.locale,
      home: MainPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get the devices locale use this:

```
import 'dart:io';

final String defaultLocale = Platform.localeName;
```

see easy_localization documentation (https://pub.dev/packages/easy_localization) for changing the language:
[image]

Found this in the Flutter documentation(https://docs.flutter.dev/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization):

Advanced locale definition
Some languages with multiple variants require more than just a language code to properly differentiate.

For example, fully differentiating all variants of Chinese requires specifying the language code, script code, and country code. This is due to the existence of simplified and traditional script, as well as regional differences in the way characters are written within the same script type.

In order to fully express every variant of Chinese for the country codes CN, TW, and HK, the list of supported locales should include:

```
supportedLocales: [
  Locale.fromSubtags(languageCode: 'zh'), // generic Chinese 'zh'
  Locale.fromSubtags(
      languageCode: 'zh',
      scriptCode: 'Hans'), // generic simplified Chinese 'zh_Hans'
  Locale.fromSubtags(
      languageCode: 'zh',
      scriptCode: 'Hant'), // generic traditional Chinese 'zh_Hant'
  Locale.fromSubtags(
      languageCode: 'zh',
      scriptCode: 'Hans',
      countryCode: 'CN'), // 'zh_Hans_CN'
  Locale.fromSubtags(
      languageCode: 'zh',
      scriptCode: 'Hant',
      countryCode: 'TW'), // 'zh_Hant_TW'
  Locale.fromSubtags(
      languageCode: 'zh',
      scriptCode: 'Hant',
      countryCode: 'HK'), // 'zh_Hant_HK'
],
```

This explicit full definition ensures that your app can distinguish between and provide the fully nuanced localized content to all combinations of these country codes. If a user’s preferred locale is not specified, then the closest match is used instead, which likely contains differences to what the user expects. Flutter only resolves to locales defined in supportedLocales. Flutter provides scriptCode-differentiated localized content for commonly used languages. See Localizations for information on how the supported locales and the preferred locales are resolved.

Although Chinese is a primary example, other languages like French (fr_FR, fr_CA) should also be fully differentiated for more nuanced localization.

Seems that you have to include them all or split the `Platform.localeName` into language and region and only use language then...

**Update**

try this:

```
final deviceLocale= Locale(Platform.localeName) 

await context.setLocale(deviceLocale.split('-')[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks. to add in my MyLangApp file or in the main.dart?

Comment: `final _newLocale = Locale(Platform.localeName)`
`await context.setLocale(_newLocale);` 
you can do this everywhere...

Comment: thanks, although i get error in writing your code "await context.setLocale(_newLocale)" , the aim was to use the Easy localization package which is already installed on the app, call the ```currentLocale``` and set the language based on the ```currentLocale```.

Comment: ok I thought so too, with that in mind I made a suggestion compatible with the EasyLocalization package. 
What is the error you get?

Comment: Im working on MyLangApp, with "print(context.deviceLocale.toString());// OUTPUT: en_US" so i get the device locale. Now i want to set the locale with ```context.setLocale(Locale('en','US'));``` but i should put "deviceLocale" inside instead of Locale(en, US)

Comment: this is what i think it may works.

Comment: `deviceLocale=Locale(Platform.localeName);`

Comment: i got error. parent.supportedLocales.contains(locale)': is not true.

Comment: Than the Locale of your device isn't listed in your supportedLocals list. Use `print(Platform.localeName);` to check whats your devices Locale.

Comment: yes i already use that, and it gives this :
en_US for English
it_US for Italian
fr_US for French

Comment: which is a bit weird, no? should be it_IT? However, i was thinking to use a ```if``` loop, like    if(deviceLocale == 'en_US'){
                    context.setLocale(Locale('en','US'));
                  }
                  else if(deviceLocale == 'it_US'){
                    context.setLocale(Locale('it','IT'));
                  }

Comment: You have only it_IT and fr_FR listed in your supportedLocales List... change ist to `supportedLocales: [
        Locale('en', 'US'),
        Locale('it', 'IT'),
        Locale('fr', 'FR'),Locale('it', 'US'),
        Locale('fr', 'US'),
      ],`

Comment: You could also only use `Locale('it')`...and leave the second parameter away

Comment: no, why? if you look my main.dart it is correct.

Comment: because `('fr','US')`means french language but date formatted like in US... if you want to suppot this, add it, or leave the second parameter away

Comment: ok. really helpful. now i got it. If i change both device language and region, then it works fine. If i set FRance and French. But if, let's say, i set French language and USA region, than it does not work, of course. And it says: Unable to load assets/translations/fr-US.json

Comment: But in this case i cannot create a file for every case (fr-FR, fr-US, fr-IT, it-FR, it_US) make sense?

Comment: it make sense... therefor I told you to only us the first parameter of Locale : `Locale('fr');`

Comment: that's what i tried, I added: 
      supportedLocales: [
        Locale('en'),
        Locale('it'),
        Locale('fr'),  to the main.dart. Also changed translation file name to ```en.json``` etc... but it is still looking for file en-IT.json or fr-US.json

Comment: ok, found out you have to include all variants or split the string of your platform locale... see edited answer

Comment: `Platform.localeName` is the only way which gave me the correct default locale of the device. Thanks.